# How to pass the CHAR as the input to the IDENTIFIED BY inside CREATE USER

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am attempting to create a database user from within a procedure in MariaDB 5.5.40

I can successfully do the following:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testUserCreate;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE testUserCreate
    (IN sDbUser CHAR(16), IN sDbPass CHAR(40))
BEGIN

CREATE USER sDbUser@'%';

END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

So the procedure has no problems with using the parameterised user name, however, when i try to do the same with the password, like so:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testUserCreate;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE testUserCreate
    (IN sDbUser CHAR(16), IN sDbPass CHAR(40))
BEGIN

CREATE USER sDbUser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD PASSWORD(sDbPass);

END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'PASSWORD(sDbPass);
```

Yes, i have tried to change it to `IDENTIFIED BY sDbPass` and other variations i could think of.

The `GRANT` generates the exact same error if i attempt to add `IDENTIFIED BY` with the variable in it.

The question is: Is it possible, and if so how, to pass the char procedure variable into the `IDENTIFIED BY` clause inside the `CREATE USER`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i guess that for whatever reason it's impossible. If somebody else will be looking for it, you will have to manually edit the mysql.user (and maybe mysql.db) table:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testUserCreate;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE testUserCreate
    (IN sDbUser CHAR(16), IN sDbPass CHAR(40))
BEGIN

INSERT INTO mysql.user (Host, User, Password) VALUES('%', sDbUser, PASSWORD(sDbPass));
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```